# sample input and expected output bash while read line: can't compare line into different values

Tags: bash, awk

I want to read a file line by line and test if the line exist in $3 in second file then print $0 else print the line.
my first file contains values like that:"
00
01
03
.
.
80
A1
A2
A3
.
.
B5"

the script work correctly until 80 but when the line became a string it doesn't work. here is the code

```
while read -r line
do
cat file2.txt | awk '
 BEGIN { FS="." 
test=0
}
('"$line"'==$1) {test=1
result=$0}
END{
if (test==1) { print result}
else { print '"$line"'}
}
'
done < file1.txt'
```

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can best help you.

Answer (score 0):

this is not the right approach with `awk`.  The idiomatic way of doing this is

```
awk 'NR==FNR {ks[NR]=$1; vs[NR]=$0; next}
             {for(k=length(ks); k>0; k--) if(k==$1) {print vs[k]; next}
              print "not found:", $1}' file2 file1
```

note that second file is provided first.  Also you mention that you're comparing $3 but the code says $1.

Comment: ths doesn't work, it always show me not found: all the lines in file 2 then not found: all the lines in file 1

Comment: did you address the note  "you mention that you're comparing $3 but the code says $1."?  Please post a samples for file1 and file2 and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

@karakfa
file2:

```
00
01
02
A1
A2
B1
B2



file 1
     B2.9.75.lkf
     B1.69.874.cds
     00.364.6478.abc
     A1.635.7452.cds
     01.36.3214.vcd
```

I want the output like that

```
00.364.6478.abc
01.36.3214.vcd
02.not found
A1.635.7452.cds
A2.not found
B1.69.874.cds
B2.9.75.lkf
```

It follow the order of file 2 and if it doesn't exist it write not found

Answer (score 0):

@M122015:try:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{q=$1;sub(/.*/,"",$1);sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"");gsub(/ /,".");A[q]=$0;next} ($0 in A){print $0 "." A[$0];next} !($0 in A){print $0".not found."}' FS="."  Input_file1  Input_file2
```

Comment: It is working for me, what is the output are you getting? Also can you check if your Input_file doesn't have any carriage returns or control M characters by doing cat -v Input_file?

Comment: @M122015: Not sure if you are using SUN OS or Solaris, if yes then on a Solaris/SunOS system, change awk to /usr/xpg4/bin/awk , /usr/xpg6/bin/awk , or nawk

Comment: yes i'm using solaris. I replace awk with nawk and there is no syntax error now. but it always show me not found:
00 .not found .
01 .not found. ....